# Algorithm to determine the real-world distances from a reference point on a plane from the pixels of a photo

Tags: python, math, image-processing, perspective, perspectivecamera

I am trying to come up with a method of converting pixel coordinates to real-world distances and I'm having trouble coming up with the math to "undo" the perspective effects.

My physical setup is a camera facing towards a plate from maybe 2 feet away. The image that the camera would see is diagrammed in the image:

[image]

So the overall square is the bounds of the picture, the dotted lines finding the image centre marked with an X (this will be the origin of my pixel coordinate grid). The plate has markings at 5 locations which describe a circle and its centre. These locations are visible to the camera (marked P1, P2, P3, P4, Pin) and the radius of the circle they describe is known and labelled as R. There is no guarantee that Pin will be overlaid on top of X, and it's quite likely that they won't be aligned perfectly, so I drew it with an offset. I will be assuming that the optical axis is perpendicular to the plate. The dot marked A is a position on the real-world plate (that is also visible to the camera) with an unknown position. I am trying to determine its radius r from the centre point, Pin.

I am able to extract the 5 points' pixel coordinates from the image with ease, as well as from point A, but the transformation from pixel to real-world coordinate is the part that's being troublesome.

I theorized that I would be able to ignore perspective and just find out the pixel distances between say P1 and P3, equal that to 2R, then get a scaling factor between pixels and real-world distances. This may give alright results, but I want to design the algorithm to be able to handle perspective issues where locations further away from the optical axis will appear smaller than those in the centre of the image.

If useful, I am able to design a calibration test where Pin is centred over X, the distance between the plate and the camera is measured, and then using the P points and R determine the angle to pixel relationship of the camera.

Would anyone be able to help me develop this algorithm or point me to some resources that may help? I have discovered Projection matrices used in 3D rendering, but I am needing to go the other direction, and none of the resources deal with points on a plane like I have.

I will likely be writing this in python but that isn't required just yet.

Comment: This question is worded in a pretty confusing way, but if you know the dimensions of the plate you are taking a picture of, if you can identify the coordinates of the edges of the plate, then you can simply perform perspective correction and the perform the steps you described. 

Look up 4 Point Homography, maybe see this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog

Also, if you use python, the library cv2 has this built in I believe.

Comment: @cmxu thanks for the links. I tried researching. Also thanks for recommending openCV. It has exactly what I'm looking for. If you make a standalone response I'll give you the best answer